# Configure powerline to display git status

Tags: powerline

I've installed powerline and the default configuration displays my current git branch. I'd also like to display the status of that branch (number of staged/unstaged files etc...) I found [powerline-gitstatus](https://github.com/jaspernbrouwer/powerline-gitstatus) which seems to do the job but I can't figure out how to configure it..

I have copied the configuration entries displayed at https://github.com/jaspernbrouwer/powerline-gitstatus#configuration to `~/.config/powerline/themes/shell/default.json` as per the instructions provided there.

The next section states

> Then you can activate the Gitstatus segment by adding it to your segment configuration, for example in .config/powerline/themes/shell/default.json:
>
> ```
> {  
>    "function": "powerline_gitstatus.gitstatus",  
>    "priority": 40  
> }
> ```

That file (`.config/powerline/themes/shell/default.json`) does not exist so I created it, added that entry, then restarted my shell. It didn't have the desired effect though. I thought maybe I should add that same entry to `.config/powerline/config.json` but I don't know where in there to put it.

If someone can guide me through this I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 10):

For me, the `default` theme did not show any VCS info at all, so I switched to `default_leftonly`. Using that theme, the following worked for me:

Make sure you have the git_status python module installed:

```
python3 -m pip install powerline_gitstatus
```

Create a file `~/.config/powerline/colorschemes/default.json` containing

```json
{
  "groups": {
    "gitstatus":                 { "fg": "gray8",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus_branch":          { "fg": "gray8",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus_branch_clean":    { "fg": "green",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus_branch_dirty":    { "fg": "gray8",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus_branch_detached": { "fg": "mediumpurple",    "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus_tag":             { "fg": "darkcyan",        "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus_behind":          { "fg": "gray10",          "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus_ahead":           { "fg": "gray10",          "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus_staged":          { "fg": "green",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus_unmerged":        { "fg": "brightred",       "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus_changed":         { "fg": "mediumorange",    "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus_untracked":       { "fg": "brightestorange", "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus_stashed":         { "fg": "darkblue",        "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
    "gitstatus:divider":         { "fg": "gray8",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] }
  }
}
```

create a file `~/.config/powerline/themes/shell/default_leftonly.json` containing

```json
{
  "segments": {
    "left": [
      {
        "function": "powerline.segments.common.net.hostname",
        "priority": 10
      },
      {
        "function": "powerline.segments.common.env.user",
        "priority": 30
      },
      {
        "function": "powerline.segments.common.env.virtualenv",
        "priority": 50
      },
      {
        "function": "powerline_gitstatus.gitstatus",
        "priority": 40
      },
      {
        "function": "powerline.segments.shell.cwd",
        "priority": 10
      },
      {
        "function": "powerline.segments.shell.jobnum",
        "priority": 20
      },
      {
        "function": "powerline.segments.shell.last_pipe_status",
        "priority": 10
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and create a file `~/.config/powerline/config.json` containing

```json
{
  "ext": {
    "shell": {
      "theme": "default_leftonly"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I also struggled quite a lot to figure out the right configuration. Once getting it right, I wrote this [Article](https://medium.com/@earlybyte/powerline-for-bash-6d3dd004f6fc) guiding one through the setup of powerline. Including installing the right font and configuring Visual Studio Code. I hope it helps.

To summarize do the following:

Create the directories:

```
mkdir ~/.config/powerline
mkdir ~/.config/powerline/colorschemes   
mkdir ~/.config/powerline/themes
mkdir ~/.config/powerline/themes/shell
```

Copy the default config files (maybe path has another python version):

```
cp ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/powerline/config_files/colorschemes/default.json ~/.config/powerline/colorschemes/
cp ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/powerline/config_files/colorschemes/solarized.json ~/.config/powerline/colorschemes/
cp ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/powerline/config_files/themes/shell/default.json ~/.config/powerline/themes/shell/
```

Add the following lines to both files in ~/.config/powerline/colorschemes

The lines need to be added to the "groups" section, and don't forget the comma in the last line before appending the lines.

```
"gitstatus":                 { "fg": "gray8",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus_branch":          { "fg": "gray8",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus_branch_clean":    { "fg": "green",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus_branch_dirty":    { "fg": "gray8",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus_branch_detached": { "fg": "mediumpurple",    "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus_tag":             { "fg": "darkcyan",        "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus_behind":          { "fg": "gray10",          "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus_ahead":           { "fg": "gray10",          "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus_staged":          { "fg": "green",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus_unmerged":        { "fg": "brightred",       "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus_changed":         { "fg": "mediumorange",    "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus_untracked":       { "fg": "brightestorange", "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus_stashed":         { "fg": "darkblue",        "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
"gitstatus:divider":         { "fg": "gray8",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] }
```

Next, edit the file ~/.config/powerline/themes/shell/default.json

Change:

```
"function": "powerline.segments.shell.jobnum",
"priority": 20
```

To:

```
"function": "powerline_gitstatus.gitstatus",
"priority": 40
```

Finally, restart the powerline daemon:

```
powerline-daemon --replace
```

After that the GIT specific information should be visible within powerline.

Comment: If the link expires, your answer isn't helpful to anyone. Please edit the most important information into your answer so that it is also useful without the link.

Comment: I was following your article before I found this answer.  It wasn't working which is why I had to continue searching.  Your article omits the daemon restart.

Comment: The medium article worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04, except all of the `~/.local` paths needed to be replaced with `/usr/local`. And as @Allen said, the post omits daemon restart. New git status prompt will appear only after restart.